# How 'juju deploy' on dedicated OpenStack availability zone/aggregate in non-MAAS environment?

Tags: juju, openstack, nova

the following problem is to solve:
- OpenStack Ocata (Ubuntu 16.04) (deployed with MAAS/Juju) with serveral availability zones / aggregates. Some are for testing, some for production
- Test-tenant in its own OpenStack domain and project
- Jump server VM in test-tenant (Ubuntu 18.04) with Juju 2.4
- Juju controller (bootstrapped from jump server in OpenStack cloud/region)
(NO MAAS in test-tenant !)

Now, we want to deploy a multi-node charm bundle with 'juju deploy' and make sure that every juju-initiated 'machine' would be created only on nova compute nodes in the 'testing' availability zone/aggregate.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Regards

PS: What I did NOT want to achieve with this question:
- Hints and tips for 'juju deploy --to 0 xxx' or 'juju add-unit --to 1 xxx'
cause the target machines must still exist. I am searching solution for a 'green field' bundle deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy command allows for zone placement.

Here is the example from the 'juju deploy --help' command:

```
juju deploy mysql --to zone=us-east-1a
(provider-dependent; deploy to a specific AZ)
```

I believe that zone placements work with openstack, so targetting `zone=testing` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working  --> Juju 2.4

```
$ openstack availability zone list
+-----------+-------------+
| Zone Name | Zone Status |
+-----------+-------------+
| internal  | available   |
| default   | available   |
| testzone  | available   |  <--- desired AZ
| nova      | available   |
+-----------+-------------+

# juju model-config zone='testzone'
# juju deploy cs:ubuntu-12 --constraints "root-disk=8G" --to zone='testzone' ubuntu01
```

Each deployed machine will start in the desired AZ.

What´s NOT working:

```
# juju deploy canonical-kubernetes --to zone='testzone'
ERROR flags provided but not supported when deploying a bundle: --to
```

So you have to deploy your services step by step and reproduce the charm-bundle with single charm and relation deployment.  :-(

I am currently investigating some possibilities forcing a zone to a local bundle.

Many thanks !